# Android: Uploading text file to google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload an empty temporary text file to google drive, however it's not succeeding. `file` is returned null. However I can upload an image from my camera using the sample from the google drive website. Do I need to set any special permission for cache? Thanks for any help.

This is my attempt:

```
java.io.File outputDir = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(); // context being the Activity pointer
java.io.File tempFile = java.io.File.createTempFile("hello", "txt", outputDir);
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", tempFile);

// File's metadata.
File body = new File();
body.setTitle(tempFile.getName());
body.setMimeType("text/plain");
File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```

How google example does it:

```
String mediaStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(mediaStorageDir + java.io.File.separator + "IMG_"
+ timeStamp + ".jpg"));

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
saveFileToDrive();


private void saveFileToDrive() {
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
 public void run() {
    try {           
        java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", fileContent);

        // File's metadata.
        File body = new File();
        body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
        body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");
        File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
    }
 });}
```

Comment: are you sure that `body` and `mediaContent` are both different from null?

Comment: are you trying to store image/jpeg file in to lain text file ,so i think you need to check once again your code.,and try to log your output after some step of execution

Comment: @NaNNy sorry, I'm not sure what you mean? Are you saying they might be null? I have checked and they are not null

Comment: @kirtiavaiya No, I'm trying to store a plain text file. The second part is google's sample for uploading an image file. Which I have no problem doing.

Comment: @roverred then are you trying to test it in emulator pr device? Try to run it into android device

Comment: @kirtiavaiya I'm running it on my samsung tab 2 tablet.

Comment: You are trying to upload an empty text file (filesize 0). Maybe google refuses such files. Did you try to upload a jpg with size 0 to see if 0 is the cause?

Answer (score 0):

greenapps answered it. I cannot upload an empty text file. I thought I could because you can upload a file with a body (title, mime type..) but without any content.

I code ended up being

```
            java.io.File tempFile = java.io.File.createTempFile("supertime", "txt");

            String tempPath = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();

            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempPath));
            bw.write("Hello");
            bw.close();

            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", tempFile);
            Log.i("Drive", tempPath);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempPath);

            StringBuilder sb = inputStreamToStringBuilder(fis);
            showText(sb);
            Log.i("Drive", "done input stream");
            // File's metadata.
            File body = new File();
            body.setTitle("Kapleck");
            body.setMimeType("text/plain");
            File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
```